# A problem from ITYM - Centro-Symmetric

Tags: contest-math

I am searching for the problems of ITYM as you can see here:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=aXR5bS5vcmd8d3d3fGd4OjdkODJiYTNhYWM0ZDNjNDU

**International Tournament of Young Mathematicians (ITYM)!**

[CentreSymmetric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gekyg.jpg)

I am so interested in this problem , but i have not ideia how to find a solution. How to determine K (n) ? That's a thing i am looking for answer. 
Is there someone here interested to explain me ?

Many Thanks ! :D

Comment: "shadow" means "orthogonal projection" in the problem?

Comment: many likely , yes